# How do I simulate a 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' using List<Map<String, String>> Objects in Java 6?

Tags: java, collections

I have 2 `List<Map<String, String>>` Objects that have intersecting data which I want to LEFT OUTER JOIN as if I were querying a DBMS. Here is a description of the Maps in each List:

Map A keys:
id, resource, address

List 1 data:

```
[
(id=1, resource="a", address="123 abc"), (id=2, resource="b", address="987 xyz")
]
```

Map B keys:
id, name

List 2 data:

```
[
(id=1, name="ZYX"), (id=1, name="WVU")
]
```

What I would like to do is matching on the 'id' key and end up with the following `List<Map<String, String>>`:

```
[
(id=1, resource="a", address="123 abc", name="ZYX"), 
(id=1, resource="a", address="123 abc", name="WVU"),
(id=2, resource="b", address="987 xyz")
]
```

At first I tried using `Collections.compare()`;

1. Taking each item from the first List>
2. Finding the corresponding item in the second `List<Map<String, String>>`
3. Merging the item from the first item and the match (if any) on 'id' into a new item
4. Adding the new item into a new `List<Map<String, String>>`

Which handles the JOIN on one side, but not on the other side. I always end up with one record with 'id'=1 and one record with 'id'=2.

I'm aware that this would be MUCH easier using Streams with Java 8 or higher, but I am stuck with Java 6.

Comment: This is unclear. In Map `B` you have duplicate keys assuming the key is `id`.  If the key consists of _both_ `id` and `name` then there is no match to anything in Map `A as there's no `name` in `A`.  You are going to need to clarify this more.

Comment: @JimGarrison There is no Map B. It's a list of maps, with the same set of keys, some mapping to identical values.

Comment: OK, I see that, but I believe the statement `Map A keys: id, resource, address` should be `Map A key: id, value: (resource, address)` for the rest of the question to make sense.

Comment: @JimGarrison I think you're missing the point. The keys are the field names, like a JSON structure.

Comment: @shmosel is correct

Comment: Instead of using list of map, create 2 pojos to substitute map A and B. Then sort the data according to id. After this you just have to compare top item from each list to get a join. Build from this further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Map<String, String>> merged = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
for (Map<String, String> map1 : list1) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (Map<String, String> map2 : list2) {
        if (map1.get("id").equals(map2.get("id"))) {
            found = true;
            Map<String, String> copy = new HashMap<String, String>();
            copy.putAll(map1);
            copy.putAll(map2);
            merged.add(copy);
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        merged.add(map1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping with my case of writers block. I will test your example and report back.

Comment: thanks again for the help! ( I upvoted your answer...)